# Paypal Smart Buttons tax get's ignored

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I'm implementing PayPal Smart Buttons SDK within our shop.
The Payload which gets sent by javascript to https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders looks like:

```
{
   "reference_id":"XYZ",
   "description":"Fonts bought from hobo typefaces",
   "custom_id":"XYZ",
   "soft_descriptor":"Soft",
   "redirect_urls":{
      "return_url":"https://dev.hobo-typefaces.com/checkout",
      "cancel_url":"https://dev.hobo-typefaces.com/cancel"
   },
   "amount":{
      "currency_code":"EUR",
      "total":"378.00",
      "shipping":0,
      "value":"360.00",
      "tax":"18.00",
      "breakdown":{
         "item_total":{
            "currency_code":"EUR",
            "subtotal":"360.00",
            "value":"360.00",
            "total":"378.00",
            "shipping":0,
            "tax":"18.00"
         }
      }
   },
   "items":[
      {
         "name":"Rosart Regular",
         "sku":"Rosart Regular",
         "unit_amount":{
            "currency_code":"EUR",
            "value":"60.00"
         },
         "quantity":"1"
      },
      {
         "name":"Rosart RegularItalic",
         "sku":"Rosart RegularItalic",
         "unit_amount":{
            "currency_code":"EUR",
            "value":"60.00"
         },
         "quantity":"1"
      },
      {
         "name":"Rosart MediumItalic",
         "sku":"Rosart MediumItalic",
         "unit_amount":{
            "currency_code":"EUR",
            "value":"60.00"
         },
         "quantity":"1"
      },
      {
         "name":"Rosart Medium",
         "sku":"Rosart Medium",
         "unit_amount":{
            "currency_code":"EUR",
            "value":"60.00"
         },
         "quantity":"1"
      },
      {
         "name":"Rosart Semibold",
         "sku":"Rosart Semibold",
         "unit_amount":{
            "currency_code":"EUR",
            "value":"60.00"
         },
         "quantity":"1"
      },
      {
         "name":"Rosart SemiboldItalic",
         "sku":"Rosart SemiboldItalic",
         "unit_amount":{
            "currency_code":"EUR",
            "value":"60.00"
         },
         "quantity":"1"
      }
   ]
}
```

While the checkout Flow works, the tax get's ignored and paypal calculates 360 EUR. Unfortunately I cannot solve this with paypal documentation. Where I'm unsure is `amount.value`, `amount.total` and the same within the `breakdown` array.

I'm thankful if one could help why my tax is ignore.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You aren't passing valid tax objects in the purchase_units array and its items array.

[Edit: page no longer exists] See here for an example: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/reference/server-integration/set-up-transaction/

See here for the API reference: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#orders_create

Comment: thanks a lot for your reply. I now those two links but do I overlook something? I cannot find an example how the object should correctly look like for adding tax.

Comment: Found something which looks promising: https://gist.github.com/t-book/da90aaf7c8b7c9ec8f433b095628603d

Comment: the first link has a full example with breakdown -> tax_total -> value and items[0]->tax->value. Those are the correct things to pass, whereas your question's code is all over the place